# Can't access a variable which was created inside a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Variables I define in the while-loop of my sql query are not available outside the loop. The following code gives no result.

```
$query= "SELECT `sqlcontent` FROM myTable";
$result= mysqli_query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $output = $row->sqlcontent;
    echo $row->sqlcontent;
}
echo $output;
```

The `echo` statement inside the while-loop works. The `echo` statement with the variable `$output` outside the loop gives no result.

Comment: The obvious reason why this wouldn't work is that you're selecting `sqltable` from the database and echoing `sqlcontent` in the HTML.

Comment: well yes. What are you trying to do?, Should there only be one result from the query, or would you expect an array of 'erm sqltable

Comment: What is $test inside the while loop?

Comment: The other thing to say is [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Comment: thanks for the mysql_* hint! But the problem is still the same :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your purpose is to just print the content then put your echo statement in while loop rather than outside of while loop.
Otherwise you can use an array to store the contents like this:-

```
$query= "SELECT `sqlcontent` FROM myTable";
$result= mysql_query($query);
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $arr[count($arr)] = $row->sqlcontent;
}
```

Now you can access the $arr outside of while loop. To get the content of the $arr array please use any of loops like for loop as follows:-

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
   // whatever you want to do with the content, just print it or use it anyway
   echo $arr[$i];
}
```

Hope it will help you.